# MySQL return number of new and used products from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using PHP and MySQL. I have tables like so:

```
categories
id  |   category |
1   |   Fujifilm
2   |   Sony
3   |   Nikon

listings
 id  | title         |Condition_id  | cat_id
 1   | Fujifilm XE-1 |     1        |   1  
 2   | Fujifilm XE-1 |     1        |   1
 3   | Fujifilm XE-1 |     2        |   1
 4   | Fujifilm X70  |     1        |   1

Conditions
 id | condition
 1  |   New
 2  |   Used
```

If someone searches for Fujifilm, I need to return:

```
2 Results found:

Fujifilm XE-1 (2 new available, 1 used available)
Fujifilm X70  (1 new available)
```

Can this be done in a single query?

So far I have:

```
    SELECT 
    listings.title,
    con.condition

    FROM listings

    JOIN conditions con ON listing.condition_id = con.id
    JOIN categories cat ON cat.id = listings.cat_id

    WHERE listings.cat.id = 1
```

If I group by title, the conditions get merged.

Comment: This is something which might best be handled in your presentation layer, rather than MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT  title,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', total_count, `condition`, 'available')) AS Result
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            listings.title,
            con.condition,
            COUNT(*) total_count
        FROM listings
            JOIN conditions con ON listings.condition_id = con.id
            JOIN categories cat ON cat.id = listings.cat_id
        WHERE listings.cat_id = 1   
        GROUP BY listings.title, con.condition
    ) a
GROUP BY title
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06812/1).